# Python-style Generator in Java

Tags: python, java, multithreading, iterator, generator

I have implemented Python-style generators within Java. I *might* be reinventing the wheel here, but I feel that the ability to define a Generator with an anonymous class is the most flexible approach. Here's the relevant code:

> generator/Generator.java

```
public abstract class Generator<T> implements Iterable<T>, Iterator<T>
{
    private Lock lock = null;
    private Lock lock2 = null;
    private Semaphore semaphore = null;
    private T curr;
    private Thread execution;
    private Runnable onTermination = null;
    private Consumer<? super T> forEachAction = null;

    public Generator(Object... params)
    {
        execution = new Thread(() ->
        {
            try
            {
                T t = get(params);
                onTermination = ThrowingRunnable.of(execution::join);
                yield(t);
                getPermit();
            }
            catch(Exception unexpected)
            {
                onTermination = ThrowingRunnable.of(() ->
                {
                    Exception e = new NoSuchElementException("Failed to retrieve element!");
                    e.initCause(unexpected);
                    throw e;
                });
                semaphore.release();
            }
        });
        execution.setDaemon(true);
    }

    @Override
    public final Iterator<T> iterator()
    {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean hasNext()
    {
        return onTermination == null;
    }

    @Override
    public final T next()
    {
        if(!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException(
                "There are no more elements to be generated by this Generator!");
        if(semaphore == null && lock == null)
        {
            lock = new ReentrantLock();
            lock2 = new ReentrantLock();
            lock.lock();
            semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
            execution.start();
            getPermit();
            return curr;
        }
        lock2.lock();
        lock.unlock();
        getPermit();
        lock.lock();
        lock2.unlock();
        getPermit();
        if(onTermination != null)
        {
            lock.unlock();
            onTermination.run();
        }
        return curr;
    }

    protected final void yield(T t)
    {
        if(forEachAction != null)
        {
            forEachAction.accept(t);
            return;
        }
        curr = t;
        semaphore.release();
        lock.lock();
        lock.unlock();
        semaphore.release();
        lock2.lock();
        lock2.unlock();
    }

    private final void getPermit()
    {
        try
        {
            if(semaphore != null)
                semaphore.acquire();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Consumes all remaining elements possible. Obviously, don't use on
     * infinite Generators.
     */
    @Override
    public void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(action);
        if(!hasNext())
            throw new IllegalStateException("Exhausted elements before calling forEach!");
        forEachAction = action;
        if(execution.isAlive())
        {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                execution.start();
            }
            catch(IllegalThreadStateException itse)
            {
                itse.initCause(// double checking
                    new IllegalStateException("Can't exhaust elements and then call forEach!"));
                throw itse;
            }
        }
        ThrowingRunnable.of(execution::join).run();
        onTermination.run();
    }

    protected abstract T get(Object... objs);
}
```

This is the code that I use for ignoring compile-time exceptions from lambdas (which should be thrown at runtime, with the default handler).

> throwing/ThrowingRunnable.java

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingRunnable extends Runnable, ExceptionFlowController
{
    public abstract void run_() throws Exception;

    @Override
    default void run()
    {
        try
        {
            run_();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            handle(e);
        }
    }

    static Runnable of(ThrowingRunnable tr, Consumer<Exception> h)
    {
        return new ThrowingRunnable()
        {
            public void run_() throws Exception
            {
                tr.run_();
            }

            public void handle(Exception e)
            {
                h.accept(e);
            }
        };
    }

    static Runnable of(ThrowingRunnable tr)
    {
        return tr;
    }
}
```

> throwing/ExceptionFlowController.java

```
/**
 * Controls exception flow by piping it into a handler.
 */
public interface ExceptionFlowController
{
    public default void handle(Exception e)
    {
        ThrowingUtil.raise(e);
    }
}
```

> throwing/ThrowingUtil.java

```
public class ThrowingUtil 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <E extends Exception> void raise(Exception e) throws E
    {
        throw (E) e;// sneakyThrow if you google it, restricted to exceptions only
    }
}
```

Here's an example of using a Generator to print the first 92 Fibonacci numbers (until 64 bits is no longer enough):

> Main.java

```
public class Main 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Generator<Number> g = new Generator<>() 
    {
      public Number get(Object[] o)
      {
        return get(0, 1);
      }

      private Number get(long fib0, long fib1)
      {
        yield(fib0);
        fib0 += fib1;
        yield(fib1);
        fib1 += fib0;
        if(fib0 < 0 || fib1 < 0)
            return null;
        return get(fib0, fib1);
      }
    };
    StreamSupport.stream(g.spliterator(),false)
    .takeWhile(Objects::nonNull)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

> 0
>   1
>   1
>   2
>   ...
>   4660046610375530309

I was a bit disappointed with the amount of concurrent primitive vomit that I had to use in order to ensure Generators were synchronized properly. Keeping this in mind, here's what I'd like to know:

1. Any generic code quality suggestions/opinions/revisions.
2. How can I cut down on the number of Locks and Semaphores/usages of Locks and Semaphores (maybe using well-named condition variables)?

**Edit:**
Here's an example where using a Generator is massively convenient compared to creating a stateful Supplier/Iterator to do the same thing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  //       0
  //   1       2
  // _   6   3   4
  //_ _ 8 9 5 _ 7 _
  Node n0 = new Node(), n1 = new Node(), n2 = new Node(),
  n3 = new Node(), n4 = new Node(), n5 = new Node(),
  n6 = new Node(), n7 = new Node(), n8 = new Node(),
  n9 = new Node();
  n0.left = n1;
  n0.right = n2;
  n2.left = n3;
  n2.right = n4;
  n3.left = n5;
  n1.right = n6;
  n4.left = n7;
  n6.left = n8;
  n6.right = n9;
  Generator<Node> g = new Generator<>() 
  {
    public Node get(Object[] o)
    {
      return get(n0);
    }

    private Node get(Node n)
    {
      if(n.left != null)
        get(n.left);
      yield(n);
      if(n.right != null)
        get(n.right);
      return null;
    }
  };
  Generator<Node> rightMost7Nodes = new Generator<Node>()
  {
    int count = 0;
    int target = 7;
    public Node get(Object[] o)
    {
      return get(n0);
    }

    private Node get(Node n)
    {
      if(n.right != null)
        get(n.right);
      if(count++ >= target)
        return null;
      yield(n);
      if(n.left != null)
        get(n.left);
      return null;
    }
  };
  System.out.println("Nodes in-order:");
  StreamSupport.stream(g.spliterator(),false)
  .takeWhile(o -> g.hasNext()) //ignore last element
  .forEach(System.out::println);
  System.out.println("Right-most 7 nodes in reverse order:");
  StreamSupport.stream(rightMost7Nodes.spliterator(),false)
  .takeWhile(o -> g.hasNext()) //ignore last element
  .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**Output:**

> Nodes in-order:
>   Node(1)
>   Node(8)
>   Node(6)
>   ...
>   Node(2)
>   Node(7)
>   Node(4)
>   Right-most 7 nodes in reverse order:
>   Node(4)
>   Node(7)
>   Node(2)
>   Node(3)
>   Node(5)
>   Node(0)
>   Node(9)

The flexibility provided by being able to `yield` mid-logic makes it extremely simple for the programmer to modify the ordering and stored state during stream creation. If the same were to be done with a Supplier/Iterator, the need to correctly modify stored state during the traversal could be unnecessarily complex (using [Morris Traversal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion-and-without-stack/) or a stack-based approach is fine for full iteration, but can get complicated when you stop midway). Furthermore, the code would be inflexible to modify for other types of traversals (pre-order/post-order). For this reason, I plan to use my Generator implementation relatively frequently - which is why I'd like for it to be reviewed as per questions 1 and 2 :)

Comment: I don't know about Python generators but I find the use of threading here to be pretty dubious.  Can you explain why you think a separate thread is needed?

Comment: Also c.f. `Stream.generate()` which seems a good deal simpler than your implementation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate(java.util.function.Supplier)

Comment: @markspace I need threading to support Python generator behavior, as `yield` statements will pause a function, save all state (context), and continue from the last `yield` on successive calls to `next()`. `Stream::generate` is insufficiently powerful for my desired use cases, as it provides *only* an infinite, unordered stream of elements, whereas my Generator intends to provide (in/)finite, ordered, stateful stream of elements. According to Stream's Javadoc: behavioral parameters "in most cases must be stateless (their result should not depend on any state that might change ...)".

Comment: Furthermore, I need control flow to go from the thread calling `next()` to switch to the Generator's `get` logic until such time as the Generator `yield`s or `returns`, at which point control flow should resume in the thread that called `next()` with the correct return value. This sounds extremely similar to a [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) to me, which is why I used threads.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so, per @markspace, you've made this a lot more complicated than it has to be. In Python, `yield` is being used to save the state of a function. In Java, you'd just use a stateful object that executes the desired function.  I'm pretty sure you could either create a `FibonacciIterator` or a `FibonacciSupplier` and meet your requirements.

In either case, every time you call `get()`/`next()`, the code runs until it hits a `return` (yield). Then state is preserved and control flow returns to the calling code. The next time `get()`/`next()` is called, execution continues from the preserved state. Both classes provide an infinite, ordered, stateful stream of elements. `Supplier` can be plugged into `Stream::generate`, while `Iterable` can be iterated over.

It is my (limited) understanding that a Python `Generator function` is just syntactic sugar that creates a Python `Iterator` which tracks execution state. This is a convenience so you can work with a function instead of an object. In your Java code, you're already tracking state yourself in your client method - by creating an infinitely deep call stack recursing on `get` with the new arguments.

If you think I'm mistaken, can you please provide a specific case that the classes below do not solve?

```
public final class FibonnaciSupplier implements Supplier<Integer> {

    private int currentNumber = 0;
    private int nextNumber = 1;

    @Override
    public Integer get() {
        final int result = this.currentNumber;
        final int sum = this.currentNumber + this.nextNumber;

        this.currentNumber = this.nextNumber;
        this.nextNumber = sum;
        return Integer.valueOf(result);
    }

}

public final class FibonnaciIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {

    private int currentNumber = 0;
    private int nextNumber = 1;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        final int result = this.currentNumber;
        final int sum = this.currentNumber + this.nextNumber;

        this.currentNumber = this.nextNumber;
        this.nextNumber = sum;
        return Integer.valueOf(result);
    }

}
```

To see an example of the stack overflow issue, try the following generator.

```
    Generator<Number> g = new Generator<Number>() {
        public Number get(Object[] o) {
            return get(0);
        }

        private Number get(long currentNumber) {
            yield(currentNumber);
            currentNumber += 1;
            if (currentNumber < 0)
                return null;
            return get(currentNumber);
        }
    };
```

You can also put a breakpoint on the line `yield(currentNumber)`, run your debugger through a few calls to `get()`, and look at the call stack. It'll look something like:

> Daemon Thread [Thread-0] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 18 in Main$1))
>       Main$1.get(long) line: 18
>       Main$1.get(long) line: 22
>       Main$1.get(long) line: 22
>       Main$1.get(long) line: 22
>       Main$1.get(Object[]) line: 14
>       Main$1.get(Object[]) line: 1
>       Main$1(Generator).lambda$0(Object[]) line: 25
>       232824863.run() line: not available 
>       Thread.run() line: 745

Those repeated `get()` calls on line 22 are you stepping into a new stack frame every time `get()` is invoked recursively.

Comment: I now realize that using `Supplier` and `Stream::generate` is the best way to go about simple element stream generation (possibly in conjunction with `limit(n)` to make the stream finite). However, I would argue that persisting state explicitly would be increasingly difficult for increasingly complex states (unlike Fibonacci). For example, providing an reverse in-order stream of elements from a binary tree (e.g. right-most n elements in a tree) would be simple using a recursive generator, whereas an iterative state-based approach would be far more complicated.

Comment: I'm not saying don't use recursion. I'm saying don't wrap a recursive method call in an unboundedly-increasing call stack with totally unnecessary concurrency checking. The `Supplier`/`Iterator` implementation can use recursion as necessary, and still remember state as part of the object.

Comment: @Avi Would you mind adding a new generator implementation to your question which shows the issue you're talking about, and how you think your generator solves a problem that a simple iterator/supplier cannot?

Comment: I'm saying that the `Supplier/Iterator` implementation makes recursion unnecessarily complicated. The Fibonacci generator could have easily contained this: `for(int i = 0; i < 46; i++) { yield(fib0); fib0 += fib1; yield(fib1); fib1 += fib0; } return null;` in its `get(int, int)` method and produced the same results. Iterative implementations with state are relatively easy in all `Supplier/Iterator/Generator` approachs. w.r.t your latest request, I'll post a generator for a binary tree once I have it complete.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing both Iterable and Iterator at the same time is a bit weird choice and while the API documentation for Iterator makes no claims about the implementation, I think most people would assume that subsequent calls to iterator() return a different object each time and those objects, if used for reading only, do not interfere with each other.

Comment: Thanks! You're right that it seems weird. I'll probably end up removing the Iterable functionality (`iterator()` method) and rename `forEach` to `forEachRemaining` as per the Iterator API (which makes more sense per my comment "Consumes all remaining elements possible").